# Invert Vector{Vector{}} grouping in Julia

Tags: julia

Given:

```
julia> x = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5]]
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [0, 1, 2]
 [3, 4, 5]
```

How can I flip the groupings so each index is collected into a vector?

```
julia> y = f(x)
3-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [0, 3]
 [1, 4]
 [2, 5]
```

(For context, I then want to compute `minimum.(y)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vertically combine elements:

```
julia> y = vcat.(x...)
3-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [0, 3]
 [1, 4]
 [2, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your goal is to calculate the `minimum.(y)`, you don't have to allocate a new temporary array for `y`. You can directly calculate the minimum from `x` by one of the following methods, both of which will be much better than splatting (`x...`).

This will be faster than all other methods,

```
minimum(reduce(hcat, x), dims=2) |> vec
```

and this will also be fast with the lowest memory allocations.

```
[minimum(y[i] for y in x) for i=1:length(x[1])]
```

Of course I assume your array is much larger than 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `invert` from [SplitApplyCombine.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/SplitApplyCombine.jl#inverta)

```
julia> x = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5]]
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [0, 1, 2]
 [3, 4, 5]

julia> invert(x)
3-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [0, 3]
 [1, 4]
 [2, 5]
```

If taking the minimum is your only reason for doing this, you can also instead do:

```
julia> x = [[0,6,2], [3,4,5]]
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [0, 6, 2]
 [3, 4, 5]

julia> minimum.(zip(x...))
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 4
 2
```

`map(min, x...)` is yet another way to do it.